# psensor not working after upgrade to 18.10

Tags: 18.10, temperature, psensor

After upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10 psensor no longer works.

If I start it from the command line, I get:

```
(process:24460): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 14:39:07.587: g_application_get_is_remote: assertion 'application->priv->is_registered' failed

(psensor:24460): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:39:07.602: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:3124:13: 'max-width' is not a valid property name

(psensor:24460): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:39:07.602: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:3125:14: 'max-height' is not a valid property name

(psensor:24460): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 14:39:07.809: gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates: assertion 'window->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed
```

The window displays OK but all the values are zero, and I get a window saying that psensor is not responding.

I note that gkrellm is able to display temperatures.

I'd be grateful for some guidance. Should I file a bug, or is there some other problem that I could fix that would restore a working psensor?

Comment: Psensor works for me, although I think it's reporting wrong values for /dev/sda. If you run psensor in a different account, does it work there? Are you running the "Ubuntu" choice at the login screen cog wheel?